# Firebase write based on grandchild value (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write to a Firebase grandchild node based on the value of one of its siblings. This value is unique for each node. Specifically, each day of the year returns a different note. My db structure is currently

= notes

=== unique key

===== day of year

===== note string

===== etc

I want to be able to query by day of year and edit the note string. What's the best way to do this? Should I make the day of the year the key? I was going to use multiple reads and a write, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way.

Comment: With your structure, you can already query the notes node for a a child that contains a particular day of the year. What's preventing that query?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it seems like the push ID doesn't benefit you because notes are already unique based on the day. It makes more sense to do a structure with the key as the day of the year, as you suggested.

```
notes: {
   day of year: {

      note string
      etc
   }
}
```

Comment: A good observation but the problem there is you only get one years worth of notes in the notes node. What if you want to keep three years worth of notes?

Comment: I assume you meant the actual full date, not just the day of the year.

Comment: In your notes node, if you use days of the year as keys, they would be 1: value, 2: value, 3: value etc. So there wouldn't be any way (as is) to have a different note on day 1 of the following year as it would overwrite this years day 1. There are many other options but using the day of the year as a key has that limitation. A more complete solution would be to use say.. a timestamp as the key  20180607 or perhaps a compound key with the year and day of the year 2018_01, 2018_02 etc.